# styles for QGIS

Tags: qgis, style

Could someone point me to a source of line and point styles for QGIS (*.qml) - railways and transmission lines are the first two I've run up against, but I know there will be more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your own styles, it is pretty easy in QGIS.  In the Layer Properties, under Style, click the Change button.

```
Step 1: Change the line colour to your desired colour (ie: black)
Step 2: Click the + (plus sign button)
Step 3: In the Symbol layers dialog box click the top Simple line
Step 4: With the top Simple line selected, change the Symbol layer type to Marker line
Step 5: A new window will pop-up, choose the vertical line in the graphics identified below
Step 6: Click Ok and Ok (you can customize the colours, spacing and sizes of all the lines
Step 7: In the Layers Properties Style tab, Click the Save as Style button and enter a name
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent - that works perfectly for the railway; trying for an electric transmission line is next...

Comment: I'm not sure what your transmission line is suppose to look like, or I would have provided an example

Comment: @Ryan or anyone that stumbles upon this, USGS styles for many features such as transmission lines can be found here https://pubs.usgs.gov/gip/TopographicMapSymbols/topomapsymbols.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Well, Underdark generously shared some of her style files on this [Github page](https://github.com/anitagraser/QGIS-resources/tree/master/styles).
pvanb also [shared](http://www.ecodiv.org/tools/legends.html) a lot of style files for both Grass and QGis.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I haven't managed to use pvanb's SLD styles so far because they use features not supported in QGIS8, but I'll keep trying.